# Duck type a Promise in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have a logging function that takes a function and logs the name, arguments, and result:

```
function log<A extends any[], B>(f: (...args: A) => B): (...args: A) => B {
    return function (...args: A): B {
        console.log(f.name);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
        const result = f(...args);
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works, and AFAICT preserves the type-safety of the passed-in function. But this breaks if I want to add special handling for Promises:

```
function log<A extends any[], B>(f: (...args: A) => B) {
    return function (...args: A): B {
        console.log(f.name);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
        const result = f(...args);
        if (result && typeof result.then === 'function') {
            result.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here the compiler complains that `.then` does not exist on type B. So I can cast to a Promise:

```
if (typeof (<Promise<any>>result).then === 'function') {
```

This too does not work, and it is a less-specific type than the generic one. The error message suggests converting to unknown:

```
const result: unknown = f(...args);
```

But now the returned type doesn't match the return signature of the HOF, and the compiler naturally won't allow it.

Now, I can use a check for `instanceof Promise`:

```
if (result instanceof Promise) {
  result.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

and the compiler is happy. But this is less than ideal: I'd prefer to do a generic test for any thenable rather than just the native Promise constructor (not to mention any oddball scenarios like the Promise constructor coming from a different window). I'd also prefer to have this be one function rather than two (or more!). And indeed, using this check to determine if a method exists on an object is a pretty common Javascript idiom.

How do I do this while preserving the return type of the original function parameter?

Comment: I guess a union type on the return value of `f` would be the right solution (`B` or a thenable).

Comment: @PaulStenne what would that look like with the type parameters?

Comment: Not sure yet, I would have to run some tests. I will do so a bit later =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd prefer to do a generic test for any thenable rather than just the native Promise constructor

This might meet your requirements:

```
if (result && typeof (result as any).then === 'function') {
  (result as any).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
} else {
  console.log(result);
}
```

If it does, you could factor it [into a user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
const isThenable = (input: any): input is Promise<any> => { 
  return input && typeof input.then === 'function';
}
```

With the user-defined type guard, the `log` function would look like this ([here it is in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20isThenable%20%3D%20(input%3A%20any)%3A%20input%20is%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20return%20input%20%26%26%20typeof%20input.then%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20log%3CA%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20B%3E(f%3A%20(...args%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20(...args%3A%20A)%3A%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(f.name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(JSON.stringify(args))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20f(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isThenable(result))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20result.then(console.log).catch(console.error)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(result)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
const isThenable = (input: any): input is Promise<any> => { 
  return input && typeof input.then === 'function';
}

function log<A extends any[], B>(f: (...args: A) => B) {
  return function (...args: A): B {
    console.log(f.name);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
    const result = f(...args);
    if (isThenable(result)) {
      result.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link as well, I'll give it a bit and if no one else throws a hat into the ring I'll accept.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was useful.